# symfony how to add a virtual column to my entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been playing around with the symfony framework and wanted to add a "virtual column" to my entity. I'll try to illustrate my requirement with pure SQL:

```
SELECT l.id, l.latlng FROM locations AS l
```

Results in an array of locations with id, latlng properties. Let's say i want to sort the results by distance from a certain starting point (latlng_start) i would amend this:

```
SELECT l.id,
   l.latlng,
   (calculation using **l.latlng** and given **[latlng_start]**) AS distance
FROM locations AS l
ORDER BY l.distance ASC
```

This would result in an array of locations with the closest location first.

Inside the symfony framework and for the sake of education, i'd create a location entity with the following properties: id, latlng and distance. Where id is automatic, latlng a string value and distance is not persisted.

How do i tell my entity to calculate the distance when it is grabbed from the database?

My guess was; use the entities constructor to set the distance using the latlng and a given parameter.

In my current solution (which doesn't satisfy me) i use createNativeQuery and an rsm to try and add this parameter yet still get the entity (not the scalar result). After that, i loop through the entities and set the distance property one by one.

[the code on github](https://github.com/tommyvdv/symfony-locator/blob/master/src/Locator/LocationBundle/Entity/Repository/LocationRepository.php#L23-L64)

Answer (score 1):

surveyssum is virtual

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('XXXBundle:Trial');

        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->select("sum(t.number_surveys) as surveyssum")
            ->where('t.study_id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $studyId)
            ->getQuery();

        $result = $query->getResult();

        $sum = $result[0]['surveyssum']; 

        return $sum;
```

Comment: Best i can do is retrieve an array collection where each item has the entity and the virtual col value alongside each other. Which means i still have to loop through these items and myEntity->setDistance() each one manually. Couldn't i just tell my entity to execute some code and set it's own property when it's called?